# How do I use the DeveloperMetadataVisibility enum in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, enums, google-drive-api

Here is the link to the [Google App Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/developer-metadata-visibility) related to DeveloperMetadataVisibility.

The problem is I want to call it in my code but I don't know how. My code looks like this:

```
const myFunction = () => {
  spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadSheet.addDeveloperMetadata("initializeDone", "true", DeveloperMetadataVisibility.DOCUMENT)

  
  const metaData = spreadSheet.getDeveloperMetadata();
  Logger.log('Metadata: ' + metaData);
  Logger.log('initializeDone: ' + metaData['initializedone']);
  
}
```

So I am trying to call the enum with `DeveloperMetadataVisibility.DOCUMENT` but this results in an error. I have noticed this before that the google enums are very poorly documented on how they should be called.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is lacking but I found the answer by trial and error:

`SpreadsheetApp.DeveloperMetadataVisibility.DOCUMENT`

In the app script editor you can try typying SpreadsheetApp or DriveApp and then a dot '.', then try to write the enum container, it will autodisplay if it exists in the object.